# Error opening Eclipse in Linux Mint; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse C/C++ for Linux Mint and it is giving me the above error when I try to open it. Does this mean that Eclipse cannot be used in Linux with its current version of OpenJDK? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

This warning is not critical however it indicates that you are using an old Eclipse version, most likely from before Java 8. You shouldn't expect that an old version of Eclipse will work with current version of OpenJDK.

At the moment we have OpenJDK 11 (potentially 12). Update your Eclipse to current version that supports OpenJDK 11 e.g. Eclipse 4.10 or 4.11.